# Does this technique have a name?

Tags: demodulation

It is possible to do IQ demodulation by using a zero crossing detector and a timer to take 4 samples of a sine wave if a reference signal is present. When there is no phase difference between the signals the 4 samples are taken at exactly 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees by using the timer.

Does this subset of lock-in/synchronous dectection have a special name? How can I best search for articles and information that has to do with this technique?

Comment: Check out what "quadrature sampling of bandpass signals" means.